# Ignore class property except for stored procedure in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

.NET Core 1.1.0, EF Core 1.1.0. I'm querying some things from my DB in such a way that it's much more efficient to delegate to a stored procedure. I want some extra things returned that aren't part of my standard class, so [until ad-hoc return types are supported](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1862) I've added these extra properties to my base class. The problem, however, is that EF now expects columns for each of these properties during all other calls.

If I configure these additional properties with this:

```
entity.Ignore(p => p.PropertyName);
```

the properties are ignored when I pull from the stored procedure. I don't know of any other way around this.

How can I get these extra properties returned from the stored procedure but ignore them all other times?

I'm running the query like this ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql)):

```
var popular = await _context.Posts
    .FromSql("EXEC usp_Post_Popular {0}, {1}", start, popCount)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: You need to handle different mappings for your DbContext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by creating a new class solely for returning the results of these procedures. I created a `DbSet` in my context configuration for the classes and called `.FromSql()` on those. No configuration is necessary in `OnModelCreating()`; I added nothing to that function.